# Nodejs scraping options

Tags: html, node.js, scrape, cheerio

I'm trying to build a scraping engine on node for my currency exchange graphs, at the moment I'm using request+cheerio, but since some bank websites don't use id/class'es in there html my code sometimes looks like:

```
var eurcur = parsedHTML('p','body')
                               .eq(1).children('table')
                                .children('tr').eq(2)
                                 .children('td')
                                  .children('table')
                                   .children('tr').eq(10)
                                    .children('td').eq(4).text()
```

Any thing else I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) with a full-featured JQuery. This allows you to use more complex selectors that Cheerio doesn't support, including selectors like [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

However, some of your `.children` calls (with should be mergable, e.g.

```
.children('td')
 .children('table')
```

to

```
.children('td > table')
```